# Where can I find tutorials and samples for MonoMac?

Tags: .net, macos, mono, monomac

I'm a C# developer and I want to port my app for MacOS. I installed all that monomac needs, but I can't find tutorials and samples for it. Can someone share links?

Comment: http://tufnelltech.blogspot.com/2012/01/hello-os-x-from-c-five-steps.html

Answer (score 4):

You can find some samples in the MonoMac github repository: https://github.com/mono/monomac/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 1):

just a couple of links to start:

- [[.NET Development for OS X](http://www.satter.org/2010/09/net-development-for-os-x.html)]
- [[Creating a simple solution using monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_A_Simple_Solution)]

Answer (score 0):

if your interested using cocoa from C# take a look to this
  - [Video Tutorial](http://groups.google.com/group/cocoa-sharp-dev/web/video-tutorial---lettercounter)
  and explore the MonoMac repository on github where you can find many C# projects covering various aspects of the OSX platform and frameworks, i think this require some skill about cocoa for which 
there is rich documentation accompanied by numerous ObjectiveC source examples on develeper.apple.com available to free members too.